# convert from boolean to byte in java

Tags: java, boolean, byte, type-conversion

I need to set byte value as method parameter. I have boolean variable `isGenerated`, that determines the logic to be executed within this method. But I can pass directly boolean as byte parameter this is not allowed and can't be cast in java. So the solution I have now looks like this:

```
myObj.setIsVisible(isGenerated ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);
```

But it seems odd for me. Maybe some better solution exists to do this?

Comment: It is weird that a `setIsVisible` method would accept anything but a boolean...

Comment: you can avoid casting 0.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

your solution is correct.

if you like you may avoid one cast by doing it the following way:

```
myObj.setIsVisible((byte) (isGenerated ? 1 : 0 ));
```

additionally you should consider one of the following changes to your implementation:

- change your method to something like *setVisiblityState(byte state)* if you need to consider more than 2 possible states
- change your method to *setIsVisible(boolean value)* if your method does what it's looking like

Comment: Would `myObj.setIsVisible((byte) isGenerated));` also work? Avoiding the `?:` operator, since the `isGenerated` is already a `true|false`, which I'm assuming already evaluates to `1|0`? Correct me if I'm wrong, I would love to know since it could be different depending on the language.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this solution. I found it on [this](http://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-boolean-to-byte-in-Java.html) very useful page

```
boolean vIn = true;
byte vOut = (byte)(vIn?1:0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not odd. It is OK.
The odd is that you need to transform typed boolean value to not self explainable byte. However sometimes we have to do this when working with legacy APIs.

BTW if you want to save memory you can use 1 bit instead of byte, so you can group several boolean flags together while using bit for each boolean value. But this technique is relevant for huge amounts of data only when saving several bytes can be significant.